# Which month to cite?

Tags: publications, citations

Which month to cite, the month of acceptance or the month on which the paper was published online?

I am using bibtex and a custom bibliographic style where specifying month is not required. However, to update my bibliographic database and to know specifically what is the norm, this question has been asked.

Comment: I usually just cite the year.

Answer (score 9):

In certain citation styles, you indeed need to add the month (respectively day and month) when you cite monthly (respectively weekly) periodicals. In which case, definitely use the month of publication: online publication if it's an online-only periodical, print publication otherwise (either print-only or print-and-online).

But such styles are a rather rare occurrence. It may be that using the month is not correct at all for what you intend. Could you give more details?

Comment: +1 for "online publication if it's an online-only periodical, print publication otherwise"